# How do I make the link box value change when choosing an application with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <h7 style="color: green">group app</h7>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
                    if(!empty($apps)){
                            foreach ($apps as $cat) {
                                ?>
    <div class="col-3" style="text-align: left;">
        <input type="radio" name="grp_app_cat"
            value="<?= $cat->cat_id; ?>"
            onclick="show_temp(this.value);"> <span>
            <?= $cat->cat_name; ?>
        </span> <img
            src="<?= base_url() ?>/asset/other/caticons/<?= $cat->icon_name ?>"
            class="cticon_footer" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    </div>
    <?php
                            }
                        }else{

                        }
                ?>
    <br> <b> <?= form_error('grp_app_cat','<p style="color: #ff4040;font-style: italic;">','</p>'); ?>
    </b>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: left;">
    <h7 style="color: green">group link <h7> <span
        style="font-size: 12px; color: red;"></span> </h7>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="grp_link" class="form-control1"
        id="focusedinput" placeholder="enter group link"
        value="<?= set_value('grp_link'); ?>"
        style="width: 100%; margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 10px;">
    <b> <?= form_error('grp_link','<p style="color: #ff4040;font-style: italic;">','</p>'); ?>
        </h7>
</div>
```

How do I make the link box value change when choosing an application with javascript

i want when user choose app from the page group link change to ex: https://t.me/ or twitter.com/